# What is a "Cookie" in Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, cookies

It was suggested that I should delete my "cookies" to solve a problem I have been having with my account. What's a cookie, in the context of Stack Exchange?

Comment: Extending the answer, it solves that you don't have to log in every time. It is also very useful to track you everywhere on the Internet (the SE doesn't do this, but the Facebook and the Google, yes.) | It may have a significantly different meaning on the [Seasoned Advice SE](https://cooking.stackexchange.com). :-)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I re-posted this question to improve my reputation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A cookie is a small piece of information that is kept on your computer by a website to remember information, e.g., login information, items in a shopping cart, etc.

For information on how to clear your cookies, please follow the relevant guide for your browser below:

- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/t5/Cookies-and-cache/Delete-cookies-to-remove-the-information-websites-have-stored-on/ta-p/1919)
- [Chrome](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/32050)
- [Internet Explorer](https://apps.centenary.edu/itfaq/0000149)
- [Edge](https://www.wiknix.com/how-to-clear-cache-and-cookies-in-microsoft-edge-browser/)
- [Opera](http://help.opera.com/opera/Windows/2393/en/private.html#deleteData)

Where possible, follow the instructions to delete cookies for one site only (Stack Exchange).